# How to make this linear time complexity to log time complexity?

Tags: java, performance, time

I was practising for a coding challenge and I got stuck up with this problem.

A and his friend bought a number each from the integer shop, A has number N and his friend has number M. A wants that both their numbers should be co-primes. To achieve this, A divides both the numbers by the largest number which can divide both the numbers. A wants to know the sum of numbers after doing this operation, help him find that sum.

Input

```
Input: 
N = 6, M = 5
Output: 
11
Explanation:
The largest number that can divide both 
5 and 6 is 1. 
After dividing, 5+6 = 11.
```

I have tried this code

```java
long sum(long N, long M){
    long divider = 1;
    long min = Math.min(N,M);
    for(long i=2; i<=min; i++)
        if(N%i==0 && M%i==0)
            divider=i;
    return (N/divider) + (M/divider);
}
```

But the expected run-time complexity is O(log(n)).
But my code gives O(n).

I'm not able to find any method to make it logarithmic. Please any help me.

Comment: If you are looking for the largest number that divides both numbers it would be faster to not start your loop at 2 and have it increase each iteration, but instead start it at the min value and decrease with each iteration. That way the first divider you find is the largest one instead of the last, allowing you to break your loop after finding a divider.

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS, yes i tried that also but didn't work out...

Comment: What do you mean with "didn't work out"? That you didn't manage to get the code right or that the improvement in run-time complexity wasn't big enough for you?

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS, i meant that it is still not O(log(n)). In the worst case scenario it is O(n) but the required is in the worst case is itself O(log(n))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use any efficient algorithm to find **GCD - Greatest Common Divisor**. E.g. you can try [Euclidean algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm) with `O(log(min(N, M))` time complexity.

```java
public static long sum(long N, long M) {
    long gcd = gcdEuclideanAlgorithm(N, M);
    return (N / gcd) + (M / gcd);
}

private static long gcdEuclideanAlgorithm(long a, long b) {
    return b == 0 ? a : gcdEuclideanAlgorithm(b, a % b);
}
```

More algorithms you can find [here](https://www.baeldung.com/java-greatest-common-divisor).